# Find Products matching ALL Categories (Rails 3.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am struggling with an ActiveRecord query in Rails 3.1.1.

I have 2 models, Product and Category, with a has_and_belongs_to_many from Product to Category (a Product can have many categories).

I am trying to write a search query that will find the Products that have ALL the specified Categories (think of a search UI where the user can choose X categories to search on).

I can do this:

```
results = Product.joins(:category_products).where('category_products.category_id' => [1,5,8])
```

but that returns Products that have ANY of those Categories (i.e. produces a SQL "IN(1,5,8)" clause).

How can I create a query that will do an ALL style of matching? E.g. find the products that have ALL of those category_ids...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a having clause:

```
@ids = [1,5,8]
query = Product.select('products.id,products.name').joins(:categories) \
               .where(:categories => {:id => @ids}) \
               .group('products.id, products.name') \
               .having("count(category_products.category_id) = #{@ids.length}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
results = Product.joins(:category_products)
[1,5,8].each do |category|
  results = results.where('category_products.category_id' => category)
end
```

Comment: This returns 0 rows for me...when it shouldn't