# How can I filter tags in a related model exclusively in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter, tags, rails-activerecord

I currently have this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_tags, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :tags, :through => :item_tags, :order => 'name ASC'

  scope :asc, order('filename ASC')
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_tags, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :items, :through => :item_tags

  scope :asc, order('name ASC')

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end

class ItemTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :tag

  scope :asc, order('position ASC')
end
```

I can easily do an inclusive filter by tags with this:

```
@items = Item.asc
@items = @items.joins(:item_tags).where('item_tags.tag_id' => params[:tags]) if params[:tags]
# params[:tags] contains a string of comma separated tags IDs like: "13,14,15"
```

But the results (of course) include all Items that have tags 13, 14 or 15.

How can I build a query that returns only Items that have tags 13 AND 14 AND 15?

eg. If I'm filtering by the 'chair' and 'modern' tags I don't want all chair Items and all modern Items. I just want all the modern chair Items.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was here: [Find Products matching ALL Categories (Rails 3.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885929/find-products-matching-all-categories-rails-3-1/11887362#11887362)

I needed to do this:

```
tags = params[:tags].split(',')
Item.joins(:tags).where(:tags => {:id => tags}).group('items.id').having("count(item_tags.tag_id) = #{tags.count}")
```