# How do I form an active record query that matches a set of ids of a has_many relationship to a set of IDs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

That's a terrible title, but part of the reason I'm even asking this questions is because I'm having a hard time finding the correct words to search for to answer this problem.

Basically, I'm trying to implement the same label filtering system that GitHub has where selecting multiple labels finds all labeled items that have all of the selected labels.  So for example, we have Users who's model includes a has_many :labels declaration.

Let's say that User "Bob" has 3 labels attached to his User model, "One", "Two", and "Three".  Then someone searching through the users selects labels "One" and "Two".  How do I form an active record query that basically says "find all users where the user's labels contains One and Two"?  Obviously I need something that could scale upwards to any number of labels.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to create already implemented functionality in such gems as [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) ([here](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_tagging) is more such gems). Can you use them instead of own solution?

Comment: It depends of the way, how you store users labels. Please provide your User model code.

Comment: I did think about implementing one of those gems, but it looks like most of them would require a significant rewrite of some pretty core code for me.  The idiots I inherited this project from didn't do that from the getgo, so i've got to work around their system.  I've also got to contend with the fact that we have a good amount of data in this existing system, so all data would need to be migrated over to the new system

Comment: I answered a fairly similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733170/how-to-find-items-with-all-matching-categories/28733456#28733456

Comment: Thanks alexvavalli, that eventually took me to the right answer for my scenario.  I initially gave adopting acts-as-taggable into my project, but it proved to be far too much of an overhaul.  I had to adopt your solution to work for my specific, overcomplicated case, but it worked in the end.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to search users with search params that are taken from another table. So you need to extend your query with a join. I'm guessing you want to search on the 'name' parameter of the labels.

```
User.joins(:labels).where(labels: {name: ["One", "Two"]})
```

which would generate this sql:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `labels` ON `labels`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE labels.name IN ("One", "Two")
```

This can turn out to be quite a heavy query if you don't manage your indexes well. As already pointed out, you could probably benefit from using a gem like acts-as-taggable-on